# Copy lines to os x clipboard from vim on remote console

Tags: macos, vim, heroku

I'm using heroku, and I've logged gotten access to bash using `heroku run bash`. I found out it was possible to install vim on heroku with this shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-jvm-buildpack-vi/vim-7.3.tar.gz --output vim.tar.gz
mkdir vim && tar xzvf vim.tar.gz -C vim
export PATH=$PATH:/app/vim/bin
```

I am now wanting to take text I yank from vim on Heroku and paste it into other editors.

To be clear, this is what I am trying to fix:
I yank all the text in a file to a vim buffer (using `yG` for instance,) but then I want to use what I've yanked by pasting it into an application like Sublime Text I'm running locally. I've also tried `"*yG`. That didn't work either.

I have a vague idea why this isn't working (the buffer I'm copying to is only accessible on the server,) but isn't there someway to do this besides selecting using the terminal?

Comment: I have no experience with osx, heroku either. could you try see if `gg"+yG` in vim works?  your `yG` just yanks the text from your current line till the end, not "all text".  also it used the `+` register (instead of `*`)

Comment: Try selecting lines in Visual Mode and then do :!pbcopy to pass the selected text to Mac clipboard. But since you will be running it remotely, I doubt it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your idea is right: because Vim runs on another machine it has no access to your local clipboard or to any local command like `pbcopy` or `pbpaste`. Also, because you use Mac OS X and (I assume) iTerm.app or Terminal.app, "X forwarding" will be of no help here (you don't use X).

So, you have two options:

- Select what you want to copy with the mouse and use your terminal emulator/system's "copy" feature.
- Set up a complicated system where you use a remote command to scp your yanked text to your local machine where it's piped into `pbcopy`. I've seen things like that in the past.

But, why don't you just do your editing remotely? Or use a VCS?

Comment: thank you @romainl. I would like to link to another of your answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694516/vim-copy-mac), and to the instructions for yank to scp to pbcopy (http://endot.org/2011/12/04/remotecopy-copy-from-remote-terminals-into-your-local-clipboard/)